# error when elaborating in design vision

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to write a code in verilog and synthes it in design vision but when elaborating design vision give below errors :

net "countS[5]" is driven by more than one source,and at least one source is constant net
net "countS[4]" is driven by more than one source,and at least one source is constant net
net "countS[3]" is driven by more than one source,and at least one source is constant net
net "countS[2]" is driven by more than one source,and at least one source is constant net
net "countS[1]" is driven by more than one source,and at least one source is constant net
net "countS[0]" is driven by more than one source,and at least one source is constant net
net "countH[5]" is driven by more than one source,and at least one source is constant net
net "countH[4]" is driven by more than one source,and at least one source is constant net
net "countH[3]" is driven by more than one source,and at least one source is constant net
net "countH[2]" is driven by more than one source,and at least one source is constant net
net "countH[1]" is driven by more than one source,and at least one source is constant net
net "countH[0]" is driven by more than one source,and at least one source is constant net

my code exist in below :

```
module main(clk,ts1,ts2,ts3,ts4,mode,res);
//clock of circuit
input clk;

//input switchs that indicate delays in test mode
input [3:0] ts1;
input [3:0] ts2;
input [3:0] ts3;
input [3:0] ts4;

//input switch that indicate mode of circuit
input [1:0] mode;

//output that indicate state of circuit
output reg [2:0] res;

//regs for counting
reg [5:0] countH;
reg [5:0] countS;

//array that indicate delays
reg [7:0] delays [3:0];

initial begin
    //resetting circuit variables
    countH = 0;
    countS = 0;
    res = 0;

    //setting delays for regular mode
    delays[0] = 30; //rg
    delays[1] = 5;  //ry
    delays[2] = 45; //gr
    delays[3] = 5;  //yr
end


//trig always whenever mode was changed
always @(mode[0] or mode[1]) begin
    //restarting timer
    countH = 0;
    countS = 0;
    //mean that mode is regular
    if(mode == 2'b00) begin
        delays[0] = 30; //rg
        delays[1] = 5;  //ry
        delays[2] = 45; //gr
        delays[3] = 5;  //yr
    //mean that mode is test mode
    end else if(mode == 2'b01) begin
        //setting delays according to input switchs
        delays[0] = ts1;    //rg
        delays[1] = ts2;    //ry
        delays[2] = ts3;    //gr
        delays[3] = ts4;    //yr
    //mean that mode is standby
    end else begin
        delays[0] = 0;  //rg
        delays[1] = 0;  //ry
        delays[2] = 0;  //gr
        delays[3] = 0;  //yr
        res = 4;
    end
end

//trig in all clocks
always @(negedge clk) begin
    countH = countH + 1;
    //count=60 mean 1sec
    if(countH == 60) begin
        //updating variables
        countH = 0;
        countS = countS + 1;

        //mean that mode is standby
        if(mode == 2) begin
            res = 4;
            countS = 0;
        //mean that mode is regular or test
        end else begin
            //checking for delay
            if(countS == delays[res]) begin
                countS = 0;
                res = res + 1;
                if(res == 4) begin
                    res = 0;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are generated by the synthesis tool, since synthesis tries to convert the design written i Verilog to hardware, but during this translation it finds that the wires `countS` (and other) are driven from several locations.

These locations are the `initial` and `always` blocks where the wires are assigned.  Think of it like doing a design using discrete gates; in this case it would also lead to a problem if multiple drive the same wires.

So you need to modify the design, so each wire/reg is only driven by one `always` block or continuous assignment, where the `initial` block is probably to be converted to some asynchronous or synchronous reset, or initial value like `reg [5:0] countS := 0;`.